# Case When in Where Clause concerning DATE

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause, case-when

Hi I am trying to create a report that doesn't take into consideration weekends. Basically today plus 2 days excluding weekends. But I am having issues with it.

```
 Where [Location Code]='MO3TRAILS'
 and
      Case when datepart(weekday,[Shipment Date]+2)='1'then [Shipment Date]+4 
 else
      Case when datepart(weekday,[Shipment Date]+2)= '7' then [Shipment Date]+4 
 else
      [Shipment Date]+2 end end
```

I keep getting "`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'end'`" as an error message.

Plan on adding this in order to filter a report in visual studio for building orders. based on today. Here is the whole current query:

```
SELECT        CASE WHEN h.[Sent To WMS] = '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 
'Ready to Ship'
        , h.[Internal Comment]
        , CASE WHEN h.[Customer Price Group] <> 'INTERNAL' AND l.[No_] 
LIKE 'P-%' THEN l.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group] ELSE 
          CASE WHEN l.[No_] LIKE 'H-%' THEN l.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group] 
ELSE '' END END AS 'POS/Repack'
        , h.No_
        , h.[Ship-to Name]
        , h.[Bill-to Name]
        , l.[Location Code]
        , h.[Pool Load]
        , h.[Shipping Agent Code]
        , l.No_ AS 'SKU'
        , CAST(ROUND(l.[Quantity (Base)], 0) AS INT) AS 'QTY'
        , CAST(ROUND(m.[Qty_ per Unit of Measure], 0) AS INT) AS 'ITEMS 
PER PALLET'
        , CAST(CONVERT(varchar, h.[Shipment Date], 101) AS date) AS 'Slot 
Date'
        , h.[Ship-to County], ROUND(l.[Gross Weight], 0) AS 'Weight'
        , CASE WHEN l.[No_] LIKE 'F-00%' THEN FLOOR(l.[Quantity (Base)] / 
m.[Qty_ per Unit of Measure]) ELSE 0 END AS [Full Pallet]
        , CASE WHEN l.[No_] LIKE 'F-00%' THEN CAST(ROUND(l.[Quantity 
(Base)], 0) AS INT)- FLOOR(l.[Quantity (Base)] / m.[Qty_ per Unit of 
Measure]) * CAST(ROUND(m.[Qty_ per Unit of Measure], 0) AS INT) ELSE 0 END 
AS Picks
        , l.[Quantity (Base)] / m.[Qty_ per Unit of Measure] AS [Pallet 
Spots]

FROM            DATASERVER.[Dynamics NAV].dbo.[Sales Header] AS 
h INNER JOIN
            DATASERVER.[Dynamics NAV].dbo.[Sales Line] AS l ON 
h.No_ = l.[Document No_] INNER JOIN
            DATASERVER.[Dynamics NAV].dbo.[Item Unit of Measure] 
AS m ON l.No_ = m.[Item No_]

WHERE        (l.[Location Code] = 'MO3TRAILS') 
          AND (m.Code = 'PALLET') 
          AND (l.[Location Code] <> 'ECW') 
          AND (m.[Item No_] <> 'D-000006') 
          AND (m.[Item No_] <> 'D-000008')

ORDER BY 'Slot Date'
```

Comment: Did you intend to compare the result of `CASE` with something else?

Comment: No. I only want the report to pull the [Ship Date]+2 for weekdays 2-4 and if weekdays are 5, or 6 [Ship Date]+4. I am excluding weekdays 7 & 1 because the report will not run on these days.

Comment: Can you include the first part of the query aswell please. I think you want the case in the select part and not the where part.

Comment: I included the real report I am running. I plan on adding the logic to it once I can get the CASE WHEN clause to work properly. I know putting it in the SELECT area will change the Ship Date to display either +2 or +4 but I want it to only show what I need to build in 2 days only excluding weekends.

Comment: When you have `AND` it assumes that you have some conditions that resolve to Boolean values before and after.  In your case on the right is **Date**.

Comment: OK. So if I'm trying to exclude weekends and show [Ship Date]+2 only in my report. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: For the Where you need always a comparison between two things. So what are you comparing the Ship Date to?   
 [Ship Date] +2 = ?

Comment: More so [Ship date]= GETDATE()+2 excluding weekends would be perfect! So if GETDATE()+2 ends up to be Saturday or Sunday, then I would want the report to exclude that and show me Monday or Tuesday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you want to achieve. When today plus 2 days is a weekend then you want the entries with shipment date in 4 days and if today plus 2 days is a weekday you want the entries with shipment date in 2 days. If I am correct, the following Where statement should do the trick.

```
    WHERE 
[Shipment Date] =
    case when datepart(weekday,getdate() + 2) in (1,7) then getdate() + 4
    else  getdate() + 2 end
```

Comment: Ok. I tried this but it doesn't like the '=' signs of [Shipment Date] = getdate() +4. It says incorrect syntax near '='

Answer (score 0):

This code is part of a `WHERE` clause, meaning everything here must resolve to a boolean "yes" or "no" result.

`CASE` statements create **values**. However, the SQL language does not have real boolean values; it only has comparison operators. Therefore, `CASE` by itself cannot produce a complete boolean expression; it can only produce the value used on one side of a comparison operator.

For this question, we have code structured like so:

```
WHERE column = value AND CASE
```

As just shown, this is not value. The result of the `CASE` expression must compare to something, e.g.:

```
 WHERE column = value AND CASE < column/value
```

Additionally, in producing those values, a CASE expression can have more than one `WHEN` section. There is no need to nest multiple CASE expressions here. Even better, us an `IN()` clause, then the first part of each `WHEN` is the same and the latter part is constant.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I finally got this sorted out to work properly using this:

```
          WHERE h.[Shipment Date]= CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,GETDATE()+2)IN (1) THEN (datediff(DAY,-4,getdate()))
          ELSE CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,GETDATE()+2)IN (7) THEN (datediff(DAY,-4,getdate())) ELSE (datediff(DAY,-2,getdate())) END END
```

Using this returned all rows that have a h.[Shipment Date] of 3/12/19 which is = getdate()+4.